# Hide the Top navigation bar and bottom bar

Tags: ios, webkit

[image: Remove the top navigation bar and bottom bar]

Hi,

I am using WEBKIT(STKWebKitViewController) for showing the url and i am unable to find a way to hide the navigation bar and bottom bar. Please let me know the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go through your STKWebKitViewController there is a method

```
self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES;
```

You can hide your navigation bar by

```
[self.navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
// Hide it in the AppDelegate where you make your root view controller if using xib.
```

To hide toolbar with tap then you have to maintain a bool for it

```
if(!tap){
        hideNav = NO;
        tap = 1;
    } else {
        hideNav = YES;
        tap = 0;
    }
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:hideNav animated:YES];

OR simply use

[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: this navigation bar and bottom bar is of WEBKIT(STKWebKitViewController) and above mention solution is not working.

Comment: @Steve Have you linked the navigation controller with your viewcontroller ?

Comment: I think you have pushed your WKWebView onto your UINavigationController using 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://github.com/sticksen/STKWebKitViewController"];
STKWebKitViewController *controller = [[STKWebKitViewController alloc] initWithURL:url];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

Comment: I have edited my answer. There will be other methods to hide bar check it out and replace them with your one on hidesBarsOnSwipe

Comment: @Steve Thank You :) Please dont forget to give tick it will help others